# If we want to choose 3 from 5 why do we not calculate 5C1 * 4C1 * 3C1?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

I feel this may be a silly question but i suddenly came across this idea and i cant get over it. I know to choose 3 from 5 we do 5C3. But to calculate the same thing i also think 5C1 * 4C1 * 3C1 should give the required answer. But it is giving the permutation. Why is it so? Can you please explain intuitively. Thanks

Comment: The second implies an ordering...first you choose one, then you choose a second from the remainders, and so on.  The first has no ordering.

Comment: do you consider ABC the same choice as BCA?

Comment: You have to divide by the number of permutations of three objects, as your computation takes the order into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the number of ways you can arrange $3$ things from $5$ in a line. Since the arrangement is not important you must divide this by $3!$.